# Add specific column to the end of a CSV file

Tags: linux, bash

It is possible to do with bash the following process?

```
"Id";"Vzor";"Name";"Number";"Number2";"Ship"
"00041534";"MGKHTYE";"2014 TREK TYAX EXPERT, GREY/YELLOW";"100";"100,30";"A"
"00041535";"MGKHTYE";"2014 TREK TYAX EXPERT 29 , BLACK/RED";"100";"453,30";"A"
"00041531";"MGKHTYSP";"2014 OPS TYAX SPORT, WHITE/GREY";"100,90";"306,60";"A"
"00046024";"MGKFAR";"2015 OPS ARGUS, DARK TEAL";"899,90";"100,90";"A"
"00046088";"MGKHFB";"2015 TREK FIREBALL 24  , BLACK";"100,90";"239,90";"A"
"00046026";"MGKHFB";"2015 OPS FIREBALL 26 , BLUE";"100,90";"359,90";"A"
```

Add a column to the first row named "Category" and (what I can't do) to individual rows add from column 3 the first two word of that column (this will be the category name):

```
"Id";"Vzor";"Name";"Number";"Number2";"Ship";"Category"
"00041534";"MGKHTYE";"2014 TREK TYAX EXPERT, GREY/YELLOW";"100";"100,30";"A";"2014 TREK"
"00041535";"MGKHTYE";"2014 TREK TYAX EXPERT 29 , BLACK/RED";"100";"453,30";"A";"2014 TREK"
"00041531";"MGKHTYSP";"2014 OPS TYAX SPORT, WHITE/GREY";"100,90";"306,60";"A";"2014 OPS"
"00046024";"MGKFAR";"2015 OPS ARGUS, DARK TEAL";"899,90";"100,90";"A";"2015 OPS"
"00046088";"MGKHFB";"2015 TREK FIREBALL 24  , BLACK";"100,90";"239,90";"A";"2015 TREK"
"00046026";"MGKHFB";"2015 OPS FIREBALL 26 , BLUE";"100,90";"359,90";"A";"2015 OPS"
```

Bash power!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use this awk command:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=";"}
   NR==1{print $0,"\"Category\"";next} {
   split($3, a, " ");
   printf "%s%s%s %s\"\n", $0, OFS, a[1], a[2]
}' file

"Id";"Vzor";"Name";"Number";"Number2";"Ship";"Category"
"00041534";"MGKHTYE";2014 TREK TYAX EXPERT, GREY/YELLOW;"100";"100,30";"A";"2014 TREK"
"00041535";"MGKHTYE";2014 TREK TYAX EXPERT 29 , BLACK/RED;"100";"453,30";"A";"2014 TREK"
"00041531";"MGKHTYSP";2014 OPS TYAX SPORT, WHITE/GREY;"100,90";"306,60";"A";"2014 OPS"
"00046024";"MGKFAR";2015 OPS ARGUS, DARK TEAL;"899,90";"100,90";"A";"2015 OPS"
"00046088";"MGKHFB";2015 TREK FIREBALL 24  , BLACK;"100,90";"239,90";"A";"2015 TREK"
"00046026";"MGKHFB";2015 OPS FIREBALL 26 , BLUE;"100,90";"359,90";"A";"2015 OPS"
```

**Explanation:**

- `BEGIN{FS=OFS=";"}` Sets input and output field separator as `;`
- `NR==1` Execute this block for record #1 only
- `{print $0,"\"Category\"";next}` Print record and literal text `"Category"`
- `split($3, a, " ")` to split field #3 by spaces and populate array `a` with individual words
- `printf` prints formatted output by taking 2 first words from array `a`

Comment: WOW, thank you. There is little problem, that newly inserted data is inserted into a new line and this breaks CSV structure. https://www.dropbox.com/s/ekt3yudgkcwta2r/Screenshot%202014-12-31%2006.18.14.png?dl=0

Comment: What I showed in answer was direct copy/paste from awk command and has no newline before last columns. Do you have DOS line ending in your csv file? Check with `cat -vte input.csv` command. If there is `^M` before each end of line then you need to run `dos2unix` command to convert to unix line ending.

Comment: @Adrian, If the line-ending thing turns out not to be the problem, the other thing you could try is running a different version of `awk`. Common ones are `awk`, `gawk`, `mawk`, `nawk`. See if any other is installed. `gawk` is the commonly used "big sophisticated" version.

Comment: Guys thank you, line-ending was the problem. Dos2Unix solved the problem. I wish you a happy new year! :)

Comment: Glad it worked out, wish you a happy new year as well :)

Comment: Let me ask one more question: How I can remove from Name column the first two words. Example: "2014 TREK ". I can list by     awk -F";" '{print $3}' input.csv | awk -F" " '{print $1 " "$2}' |  tr -d '"'   but I have no idea how to remove from the file.

Comment: Try: `awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=";"} NR==1{print $0,"\"Category\"";next} {split($3, a, " "); sub(/^[^ ]+ +[^ ]+ +/, "\"", $3); printf "%s"OFS"%s %s\"\n", $0, a[1], a[2]}' file`